# How to count occurences of number in string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a string that looks like this:

```
let str ="1,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,4,3,5,2";
```

I want to output the following to the console:

```
"1(2),2(2),3(4),4(2),5(2)"
```

Have tried map/filter but could not get this to work:

```
function dingetje(){
  let str = "1,2,3,4,1,4";
  let ar =str.split();

  let count = 0;
  let result;

  ar.map(item =>
    if (item === ar[count]){
      result =result + item;
    }
  } )

}
```

How can I write an elegant es6 solution for this?

Comment: Do you want the resulting string to have the numbers in the order they are first encountered in the input, or always ascending order?

Comment: `split()` needs to receive which string it will consider to split.

Use `str.split(',')`

Comment: Ascending order thanks

Comment: @bierhier `always ascending order` you should update this info into your question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce and Map

- split string on `,`
- loop through array and count occurrence of each number
- Loop through the entries of mapper and sort them if needed in ascending order, if you need in the same order as in input than don't sort it
- map though the entries to form `number(repetition) form
- join them by `,`

```js
let str ="1,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,4,3,5,2"

function counter(str){
  let mapper = str.split(',').reduce((op,inp)=>{
    op.set(inp, (op.get(inp) || 0 ) + 1)
    return op
  },new Map())

  return [...mapper]
         .sort((a,b)=>a[0]-b[0])  // if you need in always in ascending order
         .map(([key,value])=>`${key}(${value})`)
         .join(',')
}

console.log(counter(str))
console.log(counter("1,2,3,2,3,43,4,53,5,3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, i created you a one-liner, without sorting ;)

```
const counter = s => s
.split(',')
.reduce((r, n) => (++(r.find(({x}) => x === n) || r[(r.push({x: n, c:0})) -1]).c && r), [])
.map(({x,c}) => `${x}(${c})`)
.join(',');
```

If you want to sort it you can add a sort before the map

```
const counter2 = s => s
.split(',')
.reduce((r, n) => (++(r.find(({x}) => x === n) || r[(r.push({x: n, c:0})) -1]).c && r), [])
.sort(({x},{x:y}) => x-y)
.map(({x,c}) => `${x}(${c})`)
.join(',');
```

Ye i know its ugly, but if you just need a short solution, take it :P